# Find files whose names are shorter than 7 characters and rename them to the .new file name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Find files whose names are shorter than 7 characters and rename them to the .new file name

```
ls | grep -E "^.{,6}$"| xargs -I {} -t mv {} .new
```

no work

Comment: rename *all* of them to `.new` ?

Comment: All files in homecatalog

Comment: If you have several matching files they should all be renamed ".new" (guaranteed name clash...)?

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and a globbing pattern like this: `for file in !(???????*); do mv $file $file.new; done`

Thanks to xenoid for the correct glob pattern.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `find` with`-regex`:

... and assuming the files are in the current directory (given the initial question)

```
find -regextype egrep -regex '^.{1,6}$' -exec mv {} .new
```

Regexps in `find` accept various syntaxes so it is a good idea to be explicit. Also if you want so scan several directories, take note than unlike `name`, `-regex` applies to the whole path to the file, so an adequate patching pattern would then be `'.*/[^\]{1,6}'`

Answer (score 0):

Considering that files with names of 1-6 characters are not those with 7 characters or more:

```
mv !(???????*) .new
```

(`???????*` matches names of 7 characters or more, and the `!()` negates it). This answer assumes that you have only one possible match (which your question seems to imply in its present form).

If you have several matches then use the pattern in a`for` loop:

```
for f in !(???????*); do ... ; done
```

Comment: That does not work. 'mv' tries to move the files to into a non-existing dir named '.new'. I'm quite sure this can only be done by a for-loop.

Comment: The initial question is strange because if wouldn't work anyway if there are several matching files, only the first one would be renamed. Unless the OP implies that there will be only one match anyway, in which case this will work.

Comment: Well, the OP said 'files' which implies plural. He did not state it precisely, but in my understanding he is trying to give these files an extension '. new'. Why would you want to move several files into one hidden file?